# Nextjs Build error occurred while running build command

Tags: next.js, prerender

I'm currently building a large project with nextjs. Somehow my `npm run build` getting error even though my project perfectly fine in `npm run dev`. Most probably Error occurred in prerendering page

```
> > Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /categories/[id]: /categories/21
        /categories/[id]: /categories/22
        /categories/[id]: /categories/32
        /categories/[id]: /categories/33
        /categories/[id]: /categories/34
        /categories/[id]: /categories/35
        /categories/[id]: /categories/36
        /categories/[id]: /categories/37
        /categories/[id]: /categories/38
        /categories/[id]: /categories/39
        /categories/[id]: /categories/40
        /footerPages/[pageId]: /footerPages/3
        /footerPages/[pageId]: /footerPages/4
        /footerPages/[pageId]: /footerPages/7
        /gallery/[galleryid]: /gallery/10
        /gallery/[galleryid]: /gallery/7
        /gallery/[galleryid]: /gallery/8
        /gallery/[galleryid]: /gallery/9
        /profile/[profileId]: /profile/14
        /profile/[profileId]: /profile/15
        /profile/[profileId]: /profile/4
```

also my log shows a reason :

```
 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Do you have any production webpack files?

Comment: Show your package.json